# Settings variable values in a Moq Callback() call

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I think I may be a bit confused on the syntax of the Moq Callback methods. When I try to do something like this:

```
IFilter filter = new Filter();
List<IFoo> objects = new List<IFoo> { new Foo(), new Foo() };  

IQueryable myFilteredFoos = null;
mockObject.Setup(m => m.GetByFilter(It.IsAny<IFilter>()))
   .Callback( (IFilter filter) => myFilteredFoos = filter.FilterCollection(objects))
   .Returns(myFilteredFoos.Cast<IFooBar>());
```

This throws a exception because `myFilteredFoos` is null during the `Cast<IFooBar>()` call. Is this not working as I expect? I would think `FilterCollection` would be called and then `myFilteredFoos` would be non-null and allow for the cast.

`FilterCollection` is not capable of returning a null which draws me to the conclusion it is not being called. Also, when I declare `myFilteredFoos` like this:

```
Queryable myFilteredFoos;
```

The Return call complains that myFilteredFoos may be used before it is initialized.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This is because the code in the `Returns` method is evaluated immediately; that is, when the `Setup` method is being invoked.

However, the callback isn't being invoked until the `GetByFilter` method is invoked.

Luckily, the `Returns` method is overloaded so that you can defer its execution as well:

```
mockObject.Setup(m => m.GetByFilter(It.IsAny<IFilter>()))
    .Callback((IFilter filter) =>
        myFilteredFoos = filter.FilterCollection(objects))
    .Returns(() => myFilteredFoos.Cast<IFooBar>());
```

However, you don't need to save the value in a callback, because you can just get the parameter value directly in the `Returns` method:

```
mockObject.Setup(m => m.GetByFilter(It.IsAny<IFilter>()))
    .Returns((IFilter filter) =>
        filter.FilterCollection(objects).Cast<IFooBar>());
```

Answer (score 27):

You can just take the parameter in the return value...

```
mockObject
  .Setup(m => m.GetByFilter(It.IsAny<IFilter>()))
  .Returns((IFilter filter) =>
    {
      myFilteredFoos = filter.FilterCollection(objects);

      return myFilteredFoos.Cast<IFooBar>();
    });
```

Comment: Ya. This is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the way how are we using `Return` method

if we are using `Return(GetObject2(object1))` object1 never got initialized from callback, so it will fail to convert to Object2

The Right way to use like this `Return(()=> GetObject2())`, we have make Return method specifies a function that will calculate the value to return from the method

Don't forgot to use funcation key `()=>`

**Below Example, For your reference**

```
var object1= new List<Object>();
mockObj.Setup(_ =>_.GetMethod(It.IsAny<List<Object>>()))
            .Callback<List<Object>>((obj1) =>
            {
                object1= obj1;
            })
            .Returns(()=> GetObject2(object1));

 private List<Object2> GetObject2(List<Object> object1){
     return object1.select(_=> new Object2())
 }
```