# Moq - mocking multiple arguments

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Half the links I try off the Moq page are broken, including the one for [their official API documentation](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/labs/moq/index.html).  So I'll ask here.

I have successfully used a single "catch all" parameter like so:

```
mockRepo.Setup(r => r.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int i) => mockCollection.Where(x => x.Id == i).Single());
```

However I can't figure out how to achieve the same behavior with *multiple* parameters.

```
mockRepo.Setup(r => r.GetByABunchOfStuff(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns( ..... );
```

The `....` is the part I can't figure out.

---

*Edit in response to Jordan:*

The problem is how to represent the 3 parameters instead of just one.

How to turn:

```
(int i) => mockCollection.Where(x => x.Id == i)
```

into:

```
(int i), (string s), (int j) => mockCollection.Where(x => x.Id == i && x.SomeProp == s && x.SomeOtherProp == j)
```

Comment: The `Returns` should be the same as it would be for the first case.. What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as with a single parameter:

```
.Returns
      (
         (int i, string s, int x) 
                => mockCollection.Where
                     (
                             x => x.Id == i 
                          && x.SomeProp == s 
                          && x.SomeOtherProp == x
                     )
      );
```

Or use the generic variant of returns:

```
.Returns<int, string, int>
     (
          (i, s, x) 
               => mockCollection.Where
                    (
                         x => x.Id == i 
                         && x.SomeProp == s 
                         && x.SomeOtherProp == x
                    )
     );
```

Comment: fml...first one is what I was looking for.  Other notation is good to know as well, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you need is:

```
   mockRepo
       .Setup(r => r.GetByABunchOfStuff(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
       .Returns<int,string,int>((id, someProp, someOtherProp) =>
           mockCollection.Where(x => x.Id == i && x.SomeProp == s && x.SomeOtherProp == x));
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean how do you write the correct lambda?

```
mockRepo.Setup(r => r.GetByABunchOfStuff(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns((int i, string s, int i2) => doSomething() );
```

Answer (score 0):

See Mark Seeman's answer to this question:

[Settings variable values in a Moq Callback() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494930/settings-variable-values-in-a-moq-callback-call)

It might help.