# How to save a value to return it later?

Tags: c#, return, moq

I have an interface `ILogger` that has a `LocalTime` property to which one could add time with `AddToTime`. To mock it appropriately, I tried the following:

```
int ltime = 0;
var mlog = new Mock<ILogger>();
mlog.Setup(l => l.AddToTime(It.IsAny<int>())).Callback((int s) => {ltime +=s;});
mlog.Setup(l => l.LocalTime).Returns(ltime);
```

Although it compiles, i does not work: Probably because `Returns` evaluates the expression `ltime` at the beginning and so always returns `0`. Any suggestions how one could achieve the indented behaviour?

Edit: I need this to test it with a loop looking like this:

```
while (log.LocalTime < 1000)
        {
            log.AddToTime(500);
             ....
         }
```

As I use the time for logging purposes, it cannot simply replaced by a loop with a local variable. If `AddToTime` does nothing, the loop cannot be properly tested.

Comment: Why not make this a stub? I don't recall the right documentation of how to setup a stub in Moq, but I know you can do it. Did you try that approach?

Comment: So, you have hard-coded 1000 and 500 in your SUT? And can you describe requirements for this code? Also can you modify `Logger` or not?

Comment: You did not post rest of the test method.

Comment: I have NOT hard-coded 1000 and 500 in my code (this is an example...). I just want to mock ILogger in a way that this loop is executed once, but not infinitely often.

Comment: @JFMeier tests are coded requirements. In order to help you write test, we really need to understand requirements

Answer (score 4):

This is a test, I suggest you to avoid any logic in your test. Only place where you should have some logic is SUT you are testing. Otherwise implementation of mocked logger sneaks into test of some other class. Simply setup values you are expecting:

```
int ltime = 0;
int timeToAdd = 2;
var mlog = new Mock<ILogger>();
mlog.Setup(l => l.AddToTime(timeToAdd));
mlog.Setup(l => l.LocalTime).Returns(ltime + timeToAdd);
```

I'd even try to avoid last return setup calculation and replaced it with constant expected value. But I need to know more about logic you are testing.

Comment: The interface is used in a loop which exits after a time limit is reached. So setting constant values leads to an infinite loop or not invocation at all. Alternatively, I need something that returns a low LocalTime at first invocation, and a high value for any further invocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Returns` method instead of the `Callback`
Example here:
[Settings variable values in a Moq Callback() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494930/settings-variable-values-in-a-moq-callback-call)