Unable to grab parameter in moq setup call
I am writing some unit tests for a backend that uses MS Graph to communicate with Azure, specifically the endpoints to add and remove users in Entra groups. But when writing the test for removing users, I encountered an issue with grabbing one of the parameters in the setup call and using it in a .Callback.
The setup for the call looks like this:
MockGraphClient.Setup(g => g.Groups[GroupId].Members[userId].Reference.Request().DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))

and I would like to replace the userId variable with It.IsAny<string>() like this:
MockGraphClient.Setup(g => g.Groups[GroupId].Members[It.IsAny<string>()].Reference.Request().DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))

and grab it in a .Callback but I seem to be unable to do so. I am able to get the CancellationToken, but not the string.
I do not know if this is possible in this way or if there is another way to go about this problem?

"I seem to be unable to do so" What have you tried, and how does that not work? Please edit the post so that it provides a minimal, reproducible example.

Have you looked at any of the other posts on the topic here on Stack Overflow. Here's one post that may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2494930/126014
